# Angular-Formly: How to put an input- sm class in field

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How to set a class like .input-sm in field using angular-formly?

Ex.:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" name="test" type="text" placeholder=".input-sm">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsbin.com/jiseleb/edit?html,js,output). Just use the `ngModelElAttrs` property:

```
{
  key: 'yourKey',
  type: 'input',
  ngModelElAttrs: {
    class: 'form-control input-sm' // <-- this is it!
  },
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'Input'
  }
}
```